# External Address that isn't fixed

Tags: vba, excel

I have two workbooks `wb1` and `wb2` with worksheets `ws1` and `ws2` respectively. I want to do something like this:

```
ws1.Range("A1").Formula = "=100*" & ws2.Range("A2").Address(External:=True)
ws1.Range("A1:A10").FillDown
```

Now unfortunately `ws1.Range("A1")` ends up being `=100*ws2!$A$1` which means the `FillDown` command doesn't work as A1 is fixed.

How do I link to the otherworkbook's cell address without having it fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `Address(External:=True)`, use `Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False, External:=True)`

That will suppress the $s

Comment: Right, check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx) for more details

Comment: Excellent. Thank you user2380830! Also thankyou to Adrien Lacroix, I didn't realise Microsoft had an online resource like that!